# How can I make the custom css code for invalid values while filling the form in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I'm using the plugin from http://jqueryvalidation.org/ to validate my form. The html code is simple:

```
<form id="myform">  
     <input type="text" name="field1" />  <br/>  
    <textarea maxlength="140" style="resize:none" class="textoxarea" placeholder="zbzbzxcbcx" name="field2"></textarea> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" />x
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and the javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        errorElement: 'div',
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            terms: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 2
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

It works, as you can see in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvAPY/223/), but I would like to achieve slightly different effect. I would like to - instead of showing the error message below the fields, just change their css style, so that when the value doesn't meet its requirements - each component will get the small red border (1px).
Btw, is there a way to make the button active only when the three options above are filled properly? 
Thanks!

Comment: tried `focusCleanup: true`? or `errorClass: "invalid"`

Comment: see my updated answer for having a more cleaner approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the CSS:

```
.textox.error, .textoxarea.error,
.textox.error:focus, .textoxarea.error:focus{
    border:1px solid red; /* add the border to your input */
}
.error[generated=true]{
    display:none!important; /* hide the error message, overriding the inline styling */
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvAPY/225/)

To make the button active only when the form is valid, disable it by default:

```
<input type="submit" disabled />
```

Then, check validation of the form when an input value changes, and enable if valid:

```
$('#myform').find('input, textarea').on('change', function () {
    var btn = $('#myform').find('input[type=submit]');
    if ($('#myform').valid()) {
        btn.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvAPY/233/)

Comment: Thanks, one more thing, as I asked below too - is there any way to make the button greyed out until all fields are filled properly?

Comment: Thank you, it almost works :) The problem/bug is when I type the mail and msg - the button is still disabled (that's fine), but when I check the checkbox - nothing happens, the button is still disabled. It seems like it works only on keyUp event attached to the email/textarea, and not to the checkbox - do you know how to change this thing? Thanks!

Comment: See revised link / example above, you may have seen the link before it was updated, in the link in the comments, keyup should be replaced with `change`

Comment: Hey @SW4 , one more question - currently when I fill 2 fields and check the box - the button goes enabled (that's cool), but when I erase everything from the field - the button is still enabled and it gets disabled only after I click somewhere else - is there any way of attaching some kind of 'listener' to that fields that whenever they gets invalid - the button disables by itself without clicking anywhere else on the page first (leaving the field)?

Answer (score 2):

Add the error placement handler in the validate function like below-

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
}
```

You can handle how and where the error text label should be displayed or not be displayed at all, if you don't specify in this function callback. In this way the label text will not exist in the DOM.

And then add the css for the "error" class which is added to the control by the validator plugin like this-

```
.error{
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

**Update:**
The complete code for the cleaner way to handle your requirements-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    var validator = $('#myform ').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            terms: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 2
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {},
        success: function () {
            if(validator.numberOfInvalids() == 0)
            {
                $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
            else
            {
                $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted '); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });
    validator.form();

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click',function(){
        validator.form();
    });
});
```

Fiddle Url- http://jsfiddle.net/xvAPY/228/

Answer (score 1):

You only need this: It will also help customize error message.

```
input.error, textarea.error, input.error:focus, textarea.error:focus{
  border:1px solid red;
}
.error[generated=true]{
  color: red;
}
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xvAPY/227/)

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to make the button greyed out until all fields are filled properly?

Comment: Not sure. May be there is but you'll have to do a long process for that.

Comment: For short, you can add `disabled` attribute to submit button by default, but then there won't be any way to validate the form i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the highlight option?

```
$(".selector").validate({
  highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
$(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
$(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
  .addClass(errorClass);
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
$(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
$(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
  .removeClass(errorClass);
  }
});
```

Then add .errorClass to your CSS and define what you want it to look like.

All options can be found here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate